# Analytic functions and means of window clause

Tags: sql, oracle, average, window-functions

I'm using Oracle and SQL Developer. I have downloaded HR schema and need to do some queries with it. Now I'm working with table Employees. As an user **I need to see employees with the highest gap between their salary and the average salary of all later hired colleagues in corresponding department**. It seems quite interesting and really complicated. I have read some documentation and tried, for example LEAD(), that provides access to more than one row of a table at the same time:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name
    || ' '
    || last_name,
    department_id,
    salary,
    hire_date,
    LEAD(hire_date)
    OVER(PARTITION BY department_id
         ORDER BY
             hire_date DESC
    ) AS Prev_hiredate
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY
    department_id,
    hire_date;
```

That shows for every person in department hiredate of later hired person. Also I have tried to use window clause to understand its concepts:

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    first_name
    || ' '
    || last_name,
    department_id,
    hire_date,
    salary,
    AVG(salary)
    OVER(PARTITION BY department_id
         ORDER BY
             hire_date ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS avg_sal
FROM
    employees
ORDER BY
    department_id,
    hire_date;
```

The result of this query will be: [image: Result of query for 20 department]

[image: Result of query for 60 department]

However, it is not exactly what I need. I need to reduce the result just by adding column with gap (salary-avr_sal), where the gap will be highest and receive one employee per department. How should the result look like: for example, we have 60 department. We have 5 employees there ordering by hire_date. First has salary 4800, second – 9000, third – 4800, fourth – 4200, fifth – 6000. If we do calculations: **4800 - ((9000+4800+4200+6000)/4)=-1200, 9000-((4800+4200+6000)/3)=4000, 4800 -((4200+6000)/2)=-300, 4200 - 6000=-1800** and the last person in department will have the highest gap: **6000 - 0 = 6000**. Let's take a look on 20 department. We have two people there: first has salary 13000, second – 6000. Calculations: **13000 - 6000 = 7000, 6000 - 0 = 6000**. The highest gap will be for first person. So for department 20 the result should be person with salary 13000, for department 60 the result should be person with salary 6000 and so on.
How should look my query to get the appropriate result (what I need is marked bold up, also I want to **see column with highest gap**, can be different solutions with **analytic functions**, but should be necessarily included **window clause**)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highest Salary in each department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477040/highest-salary-in-each-department)

Comment: Please post sample data (with exact emp_id, dept_id, dates etc) in tabular format and the result in tabular format, where each employee is classified in the corresponding way (possibly with no final filtering to be able to explain each row of the result). "Let's look at department X" is an imaginary data that is very hard to operate with. Your screenshot doesn't contain this imaginary data (only one person in dept 20) and possibly your imaginary calculations have some errors/edge cases etc. Again, it is hard to provide SQL solution for this

Comment: @astentx: Thank you again for remark, updated with 2 screenshots for departments 20 and 60 and updated with the main purpose of query.

Comment: @dr: Thank you for useful link, but I need more complicated query.

Comment: @Andy Just posted the answer with your data from updated question. Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    emp (ID, EMP_NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY, DEPT) AS 
        (
            Select 601, 'HILLER',   To_Date('23-JAN-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),  4800,  60 From Dual Union All
            Select 602, 'MILLER',   To_Date('23-FEB-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),  9000,  60 From Dual Union All
            Select 603, 'SMITH',    To_Date('23-MAR-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),  4800,  60 From Dual Union All
            Select 604, 'FORD',     To_Date('23-APR-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),  4200,  60 From Dual Union All
            Select 605, 'KING',   To_Date('23-MAY-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),    6000,  60 From Dual Union All
            Select 201, 'SCOT',   To_Date('23-MAR-82', 'dd-MON-yy'), 13000,  20 From Dual Union All
            Select 202, 'JONES',    To_Date('23-AUG-82', 'dd-MON-yy'),  6000,  20 From Dual 
        ),
```

Create CTE named grid with several analytic functions and windowing clauses. They are not all needed but the resulting dataset below shows the logic with all  components included.

```sql
    grid AS
        (
          Select 
              g.*, Max(GAP) OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT) "DEPT_MAX_GAP"
          From
              (
                  Select  
                      ROWNUM "RN",
                      Sum(1) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) "RN_DEPT",
                      ID, EMP_NAME, HIRE_DATE, DEPT, SALARY,
                      --
                      Nvl(Sum(SALARY) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following), 0) "SUM_SAL_LATER",
                      Nvl(Sum(1) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following), 0) "COUNT_EMP_LATER",
                      --
                      Nvl(Sum(SALARY) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following) /
                      Sum(1) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following), 0) "AVG_LATER",
                      --
                      SALARY - 
                      Nvl((
                      Sum(SALARY) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following) /
                      Sum(1) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following)
                      ), 0)  "GAP"
                  from 
                      emp
                  Order By
                      DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID
              ) g
          Order By
              RN
        )
```

CTE grid resultiing dataset:

| RN | RN_DEPT | ID | EMP_NAME | HIRE_DATE | DEPT | SALARY | SUM_SAL_LATER | COUNT_EMP_LATER | AVG_LATER | GAP | DEPT_MAX_GAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 601 | HILLER | 23-JAN-82 | 60 | 4800 | 24000 | 4 | 6000 | -1200 | 6000 |
| 2 | 2 | 602 | MILLER | 23-FEB-82 | 60 | 9000 | 15000 | 3 | 5000 | 4000 | 6000 |
| 3 | 3 | 603 | SMITH | 23-MAR-82 | 60 | 4800 | 10200 | 2 | 5100 | -300 | 6000 |
| 4 | 4 | 604 | FORD | 23-APR-82 | 60 | 4200 | 6000 | 1 | 6000 | -1800 | 6000 |
| 5 | 5 | 605 | KING | 23-MAY-82 | 60 | 6000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6000 | 6000 |
| 6 | 1 | 201 | SCOT | 23-MAR-82 | 20 | 13000 | 6000 | 1 | 6000 | 7000 | 7000 |
| 7 | 2 | 202 | JONES | 23-AUG-82 | 20 | 6000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6000 | 7000 |

Main SQL

```sql
SELECT
    g.ID, g.EMP_NAME, g.HIRE_DATE, g.DEPT, g.SALARY, g.GAP
FROM
    grid g
WHERE
    g.GAP = g.DEPT_MAX_GAP
Order By 
    RN
```

Resulting as:

| ID | EMP_NAME | HIRE_DATE | DEPT | SALARY | GAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 605 | KING | 23-MAY-82 | 60 | 6000 | 6000 |
| 201 | SCOT | 23-MAR-82 | 20 | 13000 | 7000 |

**Without CTE and with all unnecessery columns excluded it looks like this:**

```sql
SELECT    ID, EMP_NAME, HIRE_DATE, DEPT, SALARY, GAP
FROM      
    (
        ( Select g.*, Max(GAP) OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT) "DEPT_MAX_GAP"
          From(   Select  
                      ID, EMP_NAME, HIRE_DATE, DEPT, SALARY,
                      SALARY - 
                      Nvl(( Sum(SALARY) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following) /
                            Sum(1) OVER(Partition By DEPT Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following And Unbounded Following)
                          ), 0)  "GAP"
                  From emp
                  Order By DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID
              ) g
        )    
    )
WHERE     GAP = DEPT_MAX_GAP
Order By  DEPT, HIRE_DATE, ID
```

It seems like this is all you need.

Regards...

Comment: Thank you for help, but can i do this by one query without using grid, I mean join grod and main sql?

Comment: @Andy Yes you can. I just posted it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the average salary of employees that were hired **prior to** the current employee by just adapting the rows clause of your avg:

```
    AVG(salary) OVER(
        PARTITION BY department_id
        ORDER BY hire_date 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS avg_salary
```

The `1 PRECEDING` clause tells the database not to include the current row in the window.

If you are looking for the employees with the greatest gap to that average, we can just `order by` the resultset:

```
SELECT e.*,
    AVG(salary) OVER(
        PARTITION BY department_id
        ORDER BY hire_date 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS avg_salary
FROM employees e
ORDER BY ABS(salary - avg_salary) DESC;
```

---

Finally, if you want the top "outlier salary" per department, then we need at least one more level. The shortest way to express this probably is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank employees in each department by their salary gap to the average, and then to fetch all top rows per group using `WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT e.*,
        AVG(salary) OVER(
            PARTITION BY department_id
            ORDER BY hire_date 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ) AS avg_salary
    FROM employees e
) e
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY department_id 
    ORDER BY ABS(salary - avg_salary) DESC
)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: Thank you for good example, but it's not exactly what I need. I need to see employees with the highest gap between their salary and the average salary of all later hired colleagues in corresponding department. The result should be something like on screenshot that i have provided. We have 11 departments, so I need only 11 people as result that have the highest gap between their salary and the average salary of all later hired colleagues in corresponding department. I think here should be some nested SELECT.

Comment: Should be `range between` or added one more ordering criteria, because two employees (of course) may be hired on the same date, leading to the unstable results of the same query executed for the same data multiple times

Comment: @GMB: Something is wrong. I have taken an example of department 60. We have 5 employees there ordering by hire_date. First has salary 4800, second – 9000, third – 4800, fourth – 4200, fifth – 6000. If we do calculations: `4800 - ((9000+4800+4200+6000)/4)=-1200, 9000-((4800+4200+6000)/3)=4000, 4800 -((4200+6000)/2)=-300, 4200 - 6000=-1800` and the last person in department will have the highest gap: `6000 - 0 = 6000`. Considering to your result I receive first person with salary 4800.

Comment: @Andy: I started from the `AVG()` that you provided; which windows over all employees hired **before** the current employee - which I mentionned in my answer. But your computation here in the comment seems to indicate that you want **after** rather than before?

Comment: @GMB: Yes, seems that I made a mistake, cause in my bold sentence I'm talking about all later hired colleagues... So yes, I need after, not before and if i write `1 FOLLOWING` it seems also not correct cause I receive 9000, instead of 6000

Comment: @Andy: you should be able to just arrange the `over()` clause of `avg()`, so something like: `ORDER BY hire_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` maybe?

Comment: @GMB: If I do something like this, it will change nothing, i will receive the same result as previous. I'm completely confused already:(

Comment: @GMB: do you have any other ideas that can help me? I don't know how to receive appropriate result:(

Comment: @Andy Please provide enough sample data and desired output **in text format**. It's hard to tell what is your input and how you get this results, because there's only one person per department in the (unreadable) picture attached to the question.

Comment: @Andy, you should also give better specifications regarding the latest hired person: in departments where the difference of salaries between people is small in regard of the salary, the fact that you consider the "mean of salary of people hired after" to be 0 for this person, will lead to always have this latest hired person to be the answer, which is probably not very significant in regard of the supposed objective of such an exercise

Comment: @astentx: Thank you for advice! I have updated my question to exactly show what I need with examples.

Comment: @p3consulting: Thank you for advice! I have updated my question and added example which disprove your remark.